# How to redirect to parent window(VF Page) from lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have scenario like calling a lightning component from VF page. Once value updated in lightning component the value should be update in VF page.

I have used '**window.opener.location.href**' in lightning client side controller to redirect to VF page from lightning component. But this event is blocked in lightning.

I have tried another approach in lightning component like:

```
"<a href="!javascript:top.window.opener.closeCampaignLookup('{!a.id}','','','')">{!acc.Name}</a>"
```

But could not save lightning component, since getting error like "**Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}:** "
Please help me on this.

Comment: did you find any solution, i have come across the same situation

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use `sforce.one.navigateToURL("/apex/VisualForcePageXYZ?id=" + '{!a.Id}')` to redirect to Visualforce page or `sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!a.Id}', 'detail')` to redirect to standard detail page.

Lightning mode is detected `(sforce.one != undefined)`. For example:

```
if(sforce.one != undefined) {
 sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/VisualForcePageXYZ?id=' + '{!a.Id}');
}
```